# Matlab - subtract a vector to each row of a matrix without for statement

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, vectorization, subtraction

I have a piece a code for an exam, what They want me to do in order to achieve a better grade is to implement the same thing without a second "for" statement.

The code is:

```matlab
piv = 1:n;                  %// piv: position vector
for k = 1:n-1               %// for each column :
   if ((max(abs(A(piv(k:n),k)))) > eps(normA))    %// if pivot is non zero
       [~, I] = max(A(piv(k:n),k));       %// find the max index
       I = I + (k-1);                 
       piv([k,I]) = piv([I,k]);       %// swap pivot elements
       A(piv(k+1:n),k) = A(piv(k+1:n),k)/A(piv(k),k);    %// calculate the multipliers and save them in the column 
       for j = k+1:n
            A(piv(j),k+1:n) = A(piv(j),k+1:n) - (A(piv(k),k+1:n)*A(piv(j),k));   %// multiply for multipliers and subtract them by the row 
       end 
    end
end
```

This is the Gauss factorizing method but doesn't matter, the matter is I need to have the same result without the second for e and the j variable.

Comment: `z = x - ones(size(x,1),1)*y`

Comment: they want you to implement householder transformations or givens rotations depending on the use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly *kill* the innermost loop with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). I am leaving it to you to explain to your *prof* on how it does what it does. Going through the bsxfun docs would be a good idea and in this process you might learn some [`vectorization techniques`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html). Here's the implementation -

```
parte2 = bsxfun(@times,A(piv(k),k+1:n),A(piv(k+1:n),k))
A(piv(k+1:n),k+1:n) = A(piv(k+1:n),k+1:n) - parte2
```

Comment: I want to say for other users that this is just great and works perfectly! 
But is nothing she has shown us during her lessons, I've sent her an e-mail asking what she thinks about... I hope she doesn't want something more "basic". In which case I wouldn't know how to do. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @GiuseppeTrapasso I would be really interested in hearing her opinions about it! Did she talk about bsxfun in her class? What sort of vectorizing techniques was she expecting?

Comment: My teacher proposed this solution: A(piv(k+1:n),k+1:n)=A(piv(k+1:n),k+1:n)-A(piv(k+1:n),k)*A(piv(k),k+1:n);

Comment: @GiuseppeTrapasso Ah nice! That matrix multiplication `A(piv(k+1:n),k)*A(piv(k),k+1:n)` is same as the bsxfun use listed in the solution. So, she is smart indeed! :)